# Unable to access disks in rhel 6.5

Tags: raid, redhat, hard-drive, rhel6

I work for a biology lab. We recently bought a new microscope that produces an enormous amount of data - it is simply not feasible to store it on a desktop. So, we bought a storage server - the idea being that we could stream our data to the server and then process it on the server.

The server came with RHEL 6. Now, I am a rhel noob. The server has two OS drives and 4 data drives already installed. I am able to access the OS drives via the terminal/GUI interface of RHEL. However, I cannot get to access the data drives. I have tried using gparted and the built in disk utility of RHEL. I know that the disks are connected since there is a green light outside the disk enclosure. Also, FYI, the disk utility shows that there are three megaraid sas adaptors installed on the system.

Could someone please point me to what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Matt

Comment: Did anyone actually set up RAID arrays in the RAID BIOS?

Comment: No they did not. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: If you work in a biology lab, it's likely at a university or similar larger research institution, right? Try to ask around (at the IT department or internal mailing lists or whatever) if someone local has Linux experience and is willing to help you with this.